# Rails Server immediately exists start up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I'm new to Rails and have absolutely no idea why rails server won't work. I have no doubt the answer is in all this code below but I'm completely stuck. Any ideas?

```
Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 14 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:313:in `secrets'
    from /Users/user/workspace/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:33:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
    from /Users/user/workspace/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:594:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/user/workspace/learn-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
    from /Users/user/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/user/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/user/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/workspace/learn-rails/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/user/workspace/learn-rails/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/user/workspace/learn-rails/bin/spring:16:in `require'
    from /Users/user/workspace/learn-rails/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Are you sure whatever `yml` configuration files you've made are valid?

Comment: Can you share some of the code like your seeds file and gemfile? If you do "bundle exec rails s" does it work?

Comment: It looks like your `config/secrets.yml` is invalid. Check it for valid syntax (esp. at line 14).

Answer (score 0):

The config/secrets.yml file is invalid.

YAML is whitespace sensitive so make sure to check that there are no leading whitespaces. If you aren't sure if your YAML file is valid, try pasting it into this yaml validator http://yamllint.com/ to see if its valid.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem restoring the last version of Gemfile